# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframewrok.org/tags/form/"

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframewrok.org/tags/form/"

i am getting this error on my jsp page though i have imported all the spring jar and also the dependent jars , i have also imported taglib.jar but still facing error. all my jars resides inside the /WEB-INF/lib folder in a dynamic web project.
could anyone tell me the reason behind it.
Thanks in advance..
i can show my project directory structure if anyone needed..just ask me .

Comment: Could you please provide us with the full jsp page and the /WEB-INF/lib content?

Comment: Is this the copypasted message or typed down? You've a typo in taglib URI.